# How to inject objects with list as an constructor argument using picocontainer?

Tags: java, picocontainer

I have a class which takes an list argument in its contructor:

```
 public class A{

    private List<B> bs;

    public A(List<B> bs) {
        this.bs= bs;
    } 
}
```

And I am adding this class in the container as follows:

```
    A a = someObject.createData();
    pico.addComponent(a);
```

But I am getting an exception:

```
org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$UnsatisfiableDependenciesException: A has unsatisfied dependency 'java.util.List<B>' for constructor 'public A(java.util.List)' from org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@5b970f7:6<|
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Composition Code:

```
        MutablePicoContainer pico = new DefaultPicoContainer();
        SomeClass sc= new SomeClass();
        A a = sc.createbData();
        pico.addComponent(sc);
        pico.addComponent("bs", a.getB());
        pico.addComponent("a", A.class);
```

Comment: you should have components/instances of type B or List<B> added to the container, so they could be injected when creating A

Comment: I already tried this but no luck.

Comment: post your container composition code

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide pico library version details and other details like container composition code

Comment: picocontainer:2.10.2 and composition code is above.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that you don't have class 'B' registered in container. 
There should be something like:

```
B b = new B();
pico.addComponent(b);
```

'B' can be an interface too, and Picocontainer supports injection of arrays with dependencies, so this will work:

```
public interface B {}
public class B1 implements B {}
public class B2 implements B {}

public class Test {

    private List<B> stores;

    public Test(List<B> stores) {
        this.stores=stores;
    }
}

pico.addComponent("b1",B1.class);
pico.addComponent("b2",B2.class);
pico.addComponent("test",Test.class);
```

Check also an official test case: https://github.com/picocontainer/picocontainer/blob/0f8172b7b12483920d0e3e2fcadb793d7ead4432/script/script-core/src/test/com/picocontainer/script/xml/XMLContainerBuilderTestCase.java#L868

Comment: I tried this also, I even tried to put the whole list but it is giving me same exception.

Comment: Are you sure that '.getB()' method returns class not object? : pico.addComponent("bs", a.getB());

Comment: it returns a list of B objects that we need for A's constructor.

Comment: then its wrong: this list should contain classes not objects.